# SignalR Hub is not connecting from Client, even not showing any error

Tags: c#, signalr-hub, livechat

```
Included  Scripts version 2.2.3 based on a version of signalR packages.

<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Hub Connection from Client side by script in HTML page, the code mentioned below

```
var chatProxy = $.connection.schoolAppHub;           
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function ()
        {       
          $('#btnSend').click(function ()
            {               
              chatProxy.server.broadCastMessage($("#spnName").text(), $("#txtMsg").val());
              $('#txtMsg').val('').focus();
            })
        })
```

Hub class code is also noted below

```
public class SchoolAppHub : Hub
{
    public void BroadCastMessage(String msgFrom, String msg)
    {
        Clients.All.receiveMessage(msgFrom, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Core or Non-Core?

Comment: isn't it that $.connection.signalRChatHub; should be $.connection.schoolAppHub?

Comment: If you did not specified `[HubNameAttribute]`, you should use your hub's class name (not case sensitive).

Comment: Also not showing error where, browser console?

Comment: My connection $.connection.schoolAppHub, It is Hub name. signalRChatHub is not my hub name. @ninja

Comment: Non-Core @ErikPhilips

Comment: @user3172066 if it's not your hub name, why you've used it in first place?

Comment: yes i did not specify particular [HubNameAttribute]. So i connected using hub name. I did the same what you are telling. Check my code one more time please @SeM

Comment: Yeah, unknowingly I just pasted my old code. Even I put correct schoolAppHub, it is not connecting. @SeM

Comment: @user3172066 Where is your client part? What you expect here to happen? Your current code will send your data to server and that's it. Did you debugged your code, is it getting to server?

Comment: chatProxy.client.receiveMessage = function (msgFrom, msg) {
                $('#divChat').append('<li><strong>' + msgFrom
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + msg + '</li>')